# weinre - error in console - is weinre still active?

Tags: node.js, weinre

I have used weinre in the past for debugging sites remotely because it lets me see the remote console log. Today, I came back to it to debug a remote site after some months of not using it. I'm getting this error in the console with the same setup I always used:

`Widgetic SDK: Error: No receiver for d!`

[image]
It appears to be an error in an inner lib called `Widgetic SDK`. It must be that they changed something because there is no version number in the `sdk.js` file.

I checked and I have the latest weinre version in npm (`npm install weinre`).

Is weinre still supported?

Answer (score 1):

weinre hasn't been updated in quite a while, and there are no current plans to update it in the near future.

See the yellow note on the home page https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/ for information regarding native alternatives to using weinre.

I'm not familiar with the "Widgetic SDK", so can't really provide any advice on how to fix that particular issue.

Comment: I see. However, I find weinre much better than all this... these new solutions are specific to each platform, meaning I have to setup something different to debug on each platform, and it also seems that users have to enable settings on their devices. Isn't there something like weinre?

Answer (score 0):

All that *Weinre* does in this case is display console output. If *Weinre* itself was at fault here, then there was no output whatsoever. If you see your client in the list of your *Weinre* server, then *Weinre* should be working fine.

Whether *Weinre* is active:

The way it works is you install *Weinre* and run a *Weinre* server. So whether it works depends on your *Weinre* installation, not on whatever happens online - unless you update *Weinre* that is. But as was pointed out by another user, *Weinre* is not really being developed anymore.

In my opinion, since you haven't changed anything with your setup and include the `widgetic` SDK from an online source as is suggested by the error message, in all likelihood there is a conflict between your implementation and the current version of their SDK that is being inbound by you. It does not seem like a *Weinre* error to me.

In case you are wondering, we are using *Weinre* to remotely monitor and debug web-applications as I am speaking, so it is definitely not dead yet.

Comment: Of course weinre still works but the error is in the widgetic js which is hosted remotely (judging by the stack trace). So it means the widgetic guys changed something and weinre didn't catch up? Are you not experiencing any problems like this? Do you have a self hosted widgetic js file? How did you set it up? Thanks

Comment: No, I too have no experience with widgetic. My suspicion is that there is a conflict with the usage of widgetic and Weinre merely displays the error.